# Banner HTML5 responsivo não funciona

Tags: html5, wordpress, iframe

Estou tentando incluir um banner responsivo no meu site (wp 4.9.6), seguindo um guia que encontrei na internet (sou amador).

O banner carrega normalmente no desktop e a responsividade funciona em alguns dispositivos com Android. Não funciona em tablets e IOS.

Estou usando o estilo:

```
<style> 
.banner-iframe
 {position: relative;padding-bottom: 56.25%;padding-top:30px;height:0;overflow:hidden;} 
.banner-iframe iframe
 {position:absolute;top:0;left:0;width:100%;height: 100%;}
</style>
```

Com esses parâmetros do iframe

```
<div class="banner-iframe">
 <iframe src="banner.html"
 style="border:0px #000000 none;" 
 name="meuBanner"
 scrolling="no"
 marginheight="0px"
 marginwidth="0px"
 width="728px"
 height="90px"
 frameborder="0">
 </iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: Seu iframe está como uma largura fixa de  width="728px", tente colocar de 100% para ver se resolve

Comment: Não resolveu. O banner tem um css próprio:
<meta name="ad.size" content="width=728,height=90">
var bannerJson = (...) "width":728,"height":90,"loop"

Pode ser esse o problema?

Comment: Os atributos não podem ter `px`, apenas o valor numérico.

Comment: @dvd corrigi, obrigado. Mas nada mudou

Comment: foi só uma dica. O problema pode estar mesmo no width fixo. A página do iframe tem CSS próprio? É de outro domínio?

Comment: tem CSS próprio sim. Desconfio que esse seja o problema. Está no meu domínio.

Comment: Exatamente. Coloque na imagem do banner `width: 100%; max-width: 728px;` e no iframe a mesma coisa que deve funcionar.